# How to write a C++11 template that can take a const iterator

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++-concepts

In responding to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56532/kahan-summation/) on CodeReview, I was thinking about how one might write a template function to indicate `const`-ness of a contained object.

To be specific, consider this templated function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

template <class It>
typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type average(It begin, It end) {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type real;
    real sum = real();
    unsigned count = 0;
    for ( ; begin != end; ++begin, ++count)
        sum += *begin;
    return sum/count;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v(1000);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 42);
    double avg = average(v.cbegin(), v.cend());
    std::cout << "avg = " << avg << '\n';
}
```

It takes an iterator and calculates an average based on the contained numbers, but it is guaranteed not to modify the vector through the passed iterators. How does one convey this to a user of the template?

Note that declaring it like this:

```
template <class It>
typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type average(const It begin,
    const It end)
```

doesn't work because it's not the iterator, but the thing the iterator points to, that's `const`.  Do I have to wait for [concepts](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3701.pdf) to be standardized?

**Note that I don't want to *require* const iterators, but instead to indicate that they *may* be safely used here.  That is, rather than restricting the caller, I want to convey a promise that my code is making: "I will not modify your underlying data."**

Comment: Your `average` function should accept both constant and non-constant iterators. So you cannot *require* constant iterators (some iterator type might not have correspondent constant iterators). You can however wrap the iterator into a wrapper that doesn't allow modification.

Comment: Additionally, since `iterator_traits` doesn't provide a corresponding constant iterator type, it wouldn't be possible to call a restricted `average` function from within a function that requires non-constant iterators.

Comment: @dyp: The code already *does* accept either const or non-const iterators. The question is how to convey this fact.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
template <class ConstIt>
```

It's that simple.  There's nothing to be enforced on the caller side here, as a non-`const` iterator is also usable for `const` access, so it's just API documentation, and that's what your choice of parameter identifier is - API documentation.

That does lead on to the question of enforcement on the callee/function side - so it can't be pretending it will only use the iterator for `const` access then modify elements anyway.  Should you care about that, you could accept the parameter using some identifier making it clear it wasn't meant to be used everywhere throughout the function, then create a `const_iterator` version with a more convenient identifier.  That could be tricky  as in general you don't know if the iterator type is a member of a container, let alone what that container type is and whether it has a `const_iterator` too, so some manner of Concepts would indeed be ideal - fingers crossed for C++14.  Meanwhile:

- have your caller tell you the container type,
- write your own traits, OR
- write a simple wrapper class that holds an iterator and ensures only `const` access to the referenced data escapes the interface

This last wrapper approach is illustrated below (not all of the iterator API is implemented so flesh out as needed):

```
template <typename Iterator>
class const_iterator
{
  public:
    typedef Iterator                                                 iterator_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type difference_type;
    // note: trying to add const to ...:reference or ..:pointer doesn't work,
    //       as it's like saying T* const rather than T const* aka const T*.
    typedef const typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type& reference;
    typedef const typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type* pointer;

    const_iterator(const Iterator& i) : i_(i) { }
    reference operator*() const { return *i_; }
    pointer operator->() const { return i_; }    
    bool operator==(const const_iterator& rhs) const { return i_ == rhs.i_; }
    bool operator!=(const const_iterator& rhs) const { return i_ != rhs.i_; }    
    const_iterator& operator++() { ++i_; return *this; }
    const_iterator operator++(int) const { Iterator i = i_; ++i_; return i; }
  private:
    Iterator i_;
};
```

Sample usage:

```
template <typename Const_Iterator>
void f(const Const_Iterator& b__, const Const_Iterator& e__)
{
    const_iterator<Const_Iterator> b{b__}, e{e__}; // make a really-const iterator
    // *b = 2;  // if uncommented, compile-time error....
    for ( ; b != e; ++b)
        std::cout << *b << '\n';
}
```

See it [running at ideone.com here](http://ideone.com/fAdDnO).

Comment: I don't agree with you: if something has to be `const`, then it's better to have the compiler check that your function truly doesn't change the pointer object - otherwise you'll find out only when the function is instantiated, which is very inconvenient.

Comment: @akappa: But it is just not possible here.

Comment: @gexicide: perhaps you are right (I guess you can enforce using `const` iterators with `static_assert` and some new `C++11` type-queries), but I think that Tony's argument about the usefulness of enforcing `const` is just a little simplistic.

Comment: `value_type` is not const, you have to play with `reference` or `pointer`

Comment: @Jarod42: oh - missed that - will correct the answer, thanks.

Comment: @TonyD: That would work if I *only* want to accept const iterators, but what I want to do here is not restrict the caller, but make an enforceable guarantee on *my* code.

Comment: @Edward: nope... saying `template <class ConstIt>` does *not* prevent the caller using a non-`const` iterator, per my first paragraph - it's documentation for the caller, not a restriction, saying "give me any type that supports the normal iteration semantics and allows me to read".

Comment: @TonyD: I was referring to the use of `is_const` in a `static_assert`.

Comment: @Edward: ah - sounds point - sorry for being slow to see where you were coming from.  So, new proposal edited into answer....  Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You may add some traits to see if the iterator is a *const_iterator*:

```
template <typename IT>
using is_const_iterator = 
        std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::reference>::type>;
```

And then use something like:

```
template <typename IT>
typename
std::enable_if<is_const_iterator<IT>::value,
               typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type
>::type average(It begin, It end);
```

But this will avoid the use of *iterator* which are convertible to *const_iterator*.
So it will be better to restrict *iterator* when *const* is forbidden (as in `std::sort`)

Comment: Basically, `std::vector<int> v{...}; auto avg = average(v.begin(), v.end()` would not work, would it? One could call `.cbegin()` instead, but is it that useful, really?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Even worse, you can't can't call this version of `average` inside `sort`, since the latter (only) has mutable iterators (iterators to mutable objects).

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: You have understood correctly what I mean. That's why I think that `average` should not have restriction, but you may add restriction to `std::sort`.

Answer (score 1):

> It takes an iterator and calculates an average based on the contained numbers, but it is guaranteed not to modify the vector through the passed iterators. How does one convey this to a user of the template?

You could use [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) to disable the template when non-const iterators are passed, but that would be an unnecessary limitation.

---

Another way is to accept [ranges](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) instead of iterators. This way you could write:

```
template <class Range>
typename Range::value_type average(Range const& range);
```

The user can pass a container or iterator range in there.

Comment: @dyp Yeah, `auto beg = range.begin(), end = range.end()` and do to those iterators whatever you please.

Comment: @dyp _If the range itself is shrinking while iterating, it must also be mutable._ - are you trying to shoot yourself in the foot, or shoot off the entire leg?

Comment: @dyp `Range const` provides const iterators (or, to be pedantic, iterators to constant elements).

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see the boost link. The term "Range" is ambiguous. *"are you trying to shoot yourself in the foot, or shoot off the entire leg?"* Huh? AFAIK, D's ranges are "shrinking" and it seems Java's Iterators modify themselves while iterating, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try always dereferencing the iterator through some function `deref()`.

```
template <typename It>
typename ::std::remove_reference<typename ::std::iterator_traits<It>::reference>::type const&
deref(It it)
{
  return *it;
}
```

Which would guarantee the underlying value will not be modified.